# Server selection over Angular 2?

Tags: python, node.js, django, angular2-routing

I need few suggestions on choosing server over Angular 2.

Like if i choose Django as server side, why should i choose and what are its advantages.

If i choose Node Js as server, what are its advantages over Django.

My requirement goes like: I have developed a website using Angular 2 which basically involves booking system- like order processing, send notification to customers once order status changes via API calls etc.

Im bit confused over which server to choose in my scenario since im a newbie in both Django and node js.

Answer (score 0):

Well, first of all Django is a lot more than a server. So I would skip that and look into Python servers instead.

Or you could look into node.js since you seem to be more inclined towards javascript.

Also there's small java servers available. But in your case I would probably go with node.js server since it's very easy to set up.

Comment: On the contrary, Django is explicitly **not** a server. Nor is NodeJS, for that matter.

Comment: Well, true on both accounts. I tried making the "choice" here a bit easier by simplifying things.